# jquery stop and reset counter without page reload (setInterval)

Tags: jquery, timer, setinterval, clearinterval

i have a simple clock that counts the amount of seconds passed for an AJAX call to be completed. Each request takes a different time frame and different requests can be made on the same page without refreshing.

I am using jquery to show a timer of the current request but i cannot figure out a way to clear the timer back to 0 for every new request.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#startTimer').click(function(){
    var sec = 0;
    var siID = setInterval(function() {$('#counter span').text(++sec);}, 1000);
    })
});
```

JSFIDDLE: [clicky clicky](http://jsfiddle.net/GNrUM/734/)

the problem can be replicated my pressing the 'START' button again after you press it the first time. You will see a second counter beginning from 0 while at the same time the initial counter will continue to increment and display.

**What i need is either:**

1-have the start button be able to be pressed again and restart clean from 0 every time

2-have the stop and reset button be able to be pressed to reset the counter back to 0 then press the start button to begin a new clean counter

**What i DONT want:**

1 - a counter in the function that ends it after certain seconds `if(sec == 20){die();};`
each request is a different length of time so this will not work

2 - to run another function and have the timers silently run in the background until the page is reloaded

I played around with `clearInterval()` and couldn't get anything to work...

Thank you for your time and advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this as a starting point:

```
var siID;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#startTimer').click(function(){
    var sec = 0;
    siID = setInterval(function() {$('#counter span').text(++sec);}, 1000);
    })

    $('#stopTimer').click(function() {
        window.clearInterval(siID);
        $('#counter span').text('0');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GNrUM/735/

Your variable `siID` is declared inside the click handler, therefor it no longer exists after the function exits and you can't use clearInterval with it.